# Почему отваливаются фоновые службы на Android?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, service, background

Доброго времени суток. 
Подскажите, почему может отваливаться работа фоновой службы на Android. 
Никаких сообщений об ошибках не возникает, служба просто перестает работать через несколько суток после старта.
Как можно отладить эту проблему при работе на девайсе (узнать причину остановки), либо, возможно, остановку производит сама ОС? Сталкивался с данным вопросом на этапе реализации (указывались различные типы служб и приоритет их работы). В случае с ОС (нехваткой ресурсов или чего еще) - как можно это решить?

Сам от мобильной разработки далек, поэтому буду благодарен любой информации. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно, система по сути сама решает, когда остановить ваш сервис. [Здесь](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_1_-_started_services/) подробнее про работу сервисов на xamarin.

Когда я сталкивался с такой проблемой мне помогла смена значения StartCommandResult в StartCommandResult.Sticky

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
}
```

Идея параметра в том, что при стопе сервиса, система его заново поднимет.

Comment: Да. у меня OnStartCommand так же возвращает StartCommandResult.Sticky 
Однако в моем случае данное решение не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Тут Вы не в силах что-либо изменить, так как это решает система на основе других процессов и если ей нужны ресурсы, то все будет завершено.

Убедитесь, что ваша служба не потребляет много ресурсов. Так можно лишь минимизировать вероятность ее отключение. (В принципе относиться ко всем мобильным системам т.к. тут важны баланс производительности и автономности)

Хорошая статья по работе Android(смотрите раздел App Lifecycle ) https://habrahabr.ru/company/solarsecurity/blog/338494/

Да, и вариант от @Mikhail Efremov хороший вариант, так как предназначен для перезапуска сервисов(к примеру сервис фонового воспроизведения музыки), но даже стандартные приложения аудио плеера через день-два могут закрыться, если системе нужны ресурсы.